why deref Arc with a method invoking works?
impl<R: Repository> Repository for Arc<R> {
        fn insert_walking_offer(&self, request: InsertWalkingOffer) -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = Result<String, Error>>>> {
            (**self).insert_walking_offer(request)
        }
}

why (**self).insert_walking_offer(request) works but let repository = **self, compiler will complain that

cannot move out of an Arc move occurs because value has type R,
which does not implement the Copy trait

I know I can not get the ownership of an inner object from a smart pointer, but why I can do that with a method invoking?

Method calling autorefs (if needed) - therefore, it is equivalent to (&**self).method().
